# RTC: workspace got reverted every time its associated Jenkins build gets kicked off

Tags: jenkins, rational-team-concert

RTC version: 6.0.4

Jenkins version: 2.150.1

What is happening:

1. We have a workspace that is specifically for Jenkins Integration Build only.
2. New components have been added to this workspace.
3. The Jenkins build will be kicked off by either human or a timer that is set in RTC.
4. A human or timer kicks off the jenkins build, but right before the Jennkins build checks out the workspace, all the new components are gone.
5. Jenkins checks out the version of workspace that is before new components were added (but all previously existing components have most updated change sets) and continues running.
6. The workspace will remain the reverted state without new components.

We have multiple flow targets for this workspace, we have this stream structure for several months, never have had this issue.

Looks like this only happens to this workspace, and only started to happen days ago. (might happen to others, it's just we haven't added components to other workspaces)

How to overcome this issue?

*The 1st thought is that Jenkins is doing something to the workspace, but don't know when, why and how.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include the newly added components in the `Flow Targets` section and if the component is not in the existing streams, add the stream to `Flow Targets` first. Edit `Scope Components...` if necessary.